# Emacs: what command is executed now

Tags: emacs

is it possible in Emacs to see what Elisp function is called, when I hit any key?

For example: in Projectile minibuffer I have typed filename pattern and choose between files using arrows. What function is called to choose next file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M-x view-lossage RET` to view a list of called functions.

`next-line` and `previous-line` are the functions used to navigate screen lines.
If you are using dired it will be `dired-next-line` and `dired-previous-line`.

view-lossage will only show functions in Emacs 25.1 or greater.

Comment: `view-lossage` (`C-h l`) displays the function names only in *very* recent versions of Emacs. Historically it only displayed the key strokes.

Comment: First released in Emacs 25.1, which is the latest stable release. A large proportion of people are using Emacs 24.5 or lower.

Comment: That's true. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

In most situations you can type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> followed by the key sequence you are interested in, to learn which command that sequence is bound to.

Comment: In different situations "keystroke" calls different functions. Docs for "right arrow" are the same even in Projectile's minibuffer.

Comment: `C-h k` gives a contextual answer. I don't know what you mean by "Projectile's minibuffer", so I can't comment on that specifically.

Comment: I'm not sure what the down-vote was in aid of. `C-h k` *is* the standard way to ask Emacs what a particular key sequence will do in the current situation. It's *possible* to have situations where it won't work, but in general it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can find out what a key is bound to in a given keymap.  And you can check the Emacs order of key lookup, to understand which keymap governs the current behavior.

   To look up a key in a keymap, you can use function `lookup-key` or similar -- see the Elisp manual, node [Functions for Key Lookup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Functions-for-Key-Lookup.html).

   If you use library [**`help-fns.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) then you can use **`C-h M-k`** to show all of the key bindings for a given keymap. For example, you can use `C-h M-k minibuffer-local-map`.
2. If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use [*key completion*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion): **`S-TAB`** at top level anytime shows you all keys that are possible in the current context, together with the commands they are bound to.  If you have already started a key sequence then it shows the possible completions of it.

   You can use `C-M-RET` on any of the completion candidates to show its complete documentation.